# Base URL Setting Improperly

Tags: ios, uiwebview, base-url

In my app, I scan a webpage, extract certain parts, and build an HTML String to load in a webview.  Because of this, I have to set a base URL for links that can be clicked on.  I currently use:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:self.html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ocacademy.org/ocacademy"]];
```

The issue is that subsequent links only have http://www.ocacademy.org/ in front of them instead of with the subdirectory ocacademy.  Any thoughts as to what is messing up here?

Comment: Have you tried terminating your baseURL with a slash? That would be `http://www.ocacademy.org/ocacademy/`.

Comment: @Till Tried that, and it produced the same results.  Even pressing on the link to pull up the action sheet shows the URL missing the /ocacademy/ part.

Comment: Tough luck then. I tried to find a proper description on what Apple considers to be a base-URL, couldnt find any. Guess they define it as schema+domain/IP and ignore any additional paths.

Comment: Any work arounds that might work on this?

Comment: Show us an example (a small one!) of an HTML string you're loading in. I suspect the links in it begin with a `/` which means to ignore any path you may have specified as part of the base URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either append a `/` or more explicitly `/name_of_html_file.html` to the base URL.

Any trailing filename in the base URL will be stripped off when constructing a relative URL (`ocacademy` in this case).

So given a base URL of `http://www.ocacademy.org/ocacademy` and a relative reference to `image.png`, the `ocacademy` is stripped off to give a parent directory `http://www.ocacademy.org/` and the resulting URL will be `http://www.ocacademy.org/image.png`.

If the base URL is `http://www.ocacademy.org/ocacademy/.*` then the `.*` is stripped off before constructing the URL and you will get `http://www.ocacademy.org/ocacademy/image.png` (what you want).